# Отправить checkbox в php скрипт

Tags: jquery

Нужно отправить `checkbox` в `php` скрипт. Например

```
var check = $('#checkbox').val();
data: {'check': check}
```

serialize не предлагать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может быть, вам поможет атрибут *checked*:

`var value = $('selector').is(':checked')`

Ну и, собственно, скрипт отправки значения будет выглядеть так:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ваш урл",
    type: "POST",
    data: { checked: value }
}).done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
});
```